# CMake a cpp program with PCL and VTK

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cmake, vtk, point-cloud-library

I have a cpp file that I'm trying to make and when I run my makefile, I'm getting some Linker errors, like the ones here:

http://pastebin.com/7tadTG3D

I'm new to C++, but I'm pretty sure the errors lie in linking the libraries, specifically PCL and VTK. My main.cpp compiles fine now with the pcl and vtk header files, but it's the object files that won't work. I'm trying to figure out how to create a cmake file to compile all my code, I have been using a makefile up until now.

Makefile:

```
CC = g++-4.4
CFLAGS = -I ../include -I ~/../../usr/include/pcl-1.7/ -I ~/../../usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src -I ~/../../usr/include/vtk-5.8
# first location: pmd header files (include, back one directory)
# second location: your pcl header files
# third location: your eigen header files
# fourth location: your vtk header files
LDFLAGS = -L. -lpmdaccess2 -lc

all: main
main: main.cpp copysdk copyplugins
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  -c -o main.o main.cpp
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o main main.o

copysdk:
    cp ../bin/libpmdaccess* ./  # bin folder back one directory

copyplugins:
    cp ../bin/camboardnano* ./

clean: 
    rm main
    rm main.o
    rm camboardnano*
    rm libpmdaccess*
```

I'm trying to figure out how to build my project with cmake, but I'm having trouble finding a good tutorial. I'm using a CamBoard Nano, so the bin directory contains camboardnano.L32.pap, camboardnanoproc.L32.ppp, and libpmdaccess2.so. Include contains pmddatadescription.h, pmdsdk2.h, and pmdsdk2common.h, as well as stdafx.h. Main.cpp uses several libraries (OpenNI, VTK, Eigen, and PCL). Can anyone link me to a tutorial that will help me transfer my makefile to use cmake, or explain cmake? On PCL's site, I found a tutorial that uses a cmake: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcl_visualizer.php I think this is what I need to do. Could someone explain each line in the CMakeLists.txt listed here?

Comment: I created a CMakeLists.txt file that fixed all of my problems: http://pastebin.com/R5ri8uVv

Comment: Please add this as an answer (with the actual content of your pastebin instead of just a link) and then accept your own answer.